# ms word index only subentry

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document where I've marked various entries for the Index. The entries are like this:

```
Inland Empire
    David Shaver
    John Jameson
JM Granny
    Justin Flatterer
    Mary Martinson
Palouse Poppies
    Sara Talk
    Eddie Haskell
```

I've marked each Organization as a Main Entry and each Person as a SubEntry.

I need TWO indices.

1) List of companies with all their people (similar to as shown, above).

2) List of ONLY the people. No companies.

How can I generate an index that shows only the Subentries?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions; this is an end-user question. You need to ask this in an end-user forum such as SuperUser or the Microsoft Answers site. FWIW, though, as I recall you need an additional set of XE tags with an identifier for the second index.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear -- though I did put a VBA tag in the question. I'm wanting to know how to do this programmatically.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service - you may want to read up on the site guidelines in [help]. You need to have made an effort, show us the code you've tried that's not working and ask a very specific question. I'll give you a hint: try the macro recorder to get started...